# How to programmatically disable product for all store-view in Magento?

Tags: magento

I want to disable product programmatically for all store view. Please help me

I tried with the following... but no luck

```
$storeId = 0;                               
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product_id, $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly `$storeId=0` is default store id for admin if you want disable product for all store view then you can set `$storeId=Mage:app()->getStoreId()`// this is for current store id

after that you can disable all product

```
$product_id=1;
$storeId=Mage::app()->getStoreId();
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product_id, $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
```

**EDIT**

*This is for all store view i think this is the dirty way to achieve this*

```
<?php
    $allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();
    foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId => $val)
    {
        $_storeId[] = Mage::app()->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getId();
    }
    for($i=0;$i<count($_storeId);$i++)
    {
        $product_id=1;
        $storeId=$_storeId[$i];
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product_id, $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
    }
?>
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: Sorry for the delay to get back on this. It actually working perfect. But i have another question and which is related to the above one. My question is - How to disable a product programmatically for only Admin View or Default View?

Comment: Very strange way to get all store IDs - you can just iterate through the result of getStores() and you will get a list of store objects. So there is no need to collect your store IDs like this and then run through a second loop. Way to much code for such a simple task (see my answer for shorter version).

Answer (score 1):

By default the **scope** of **status** **attribute** is set to **store** , if we will set it to global under manage attributes , than we can update status for all store views with below code.

```
$loadproduct = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load("product_id");
            $loadproduct->setStatus(2); 
            $loadproduct->save();
```

thanks

Comment: You should'n load a product just to update a single attribute - this leads to a performance issue when you have a lot of products.

Comment: @MatthiasKleine Kleine  Ok please provide your solution

Comment: In general you should always use the resource model of eav entities to update a single attribute. For product status I've just posted my solution, but you can do it like this when you want to update another product attribute:         

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($productId), array('status' => $value), $storeId);

Answer (score 1):

There's a much shorter way than in the answer of Keyur Shah:

```
foreach (Mage::app()->getStores() as $store) {
    Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($productId, $store->getId(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
}
```